# Super basic Amazon SimpleDB authentication tutorial?

Tags: python, http, authentication, amazon-web-services, amazon-simpledb

I'm a Simple DB newb and am looking for some step-by-step instructions about how to generate the correct signature. Some of the tutorials/sample code I'm seeing say it's a combination of a timestamp, the service you're using, and the method you're requesting be done on that service. Is this correct? I speak python if someone can provide code to generate it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to use `boto`. It's [documentation](http://boto.cloudhackers.com/) is really great, and they have a [page specifically about SimpleDB](http://code.google.com/p/boto/wiki/SimpleDbIntro).

Answer (score 1):

You may like to view this: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9YEGwmYejt4